# civix permission denied errors in /usr/local/bin when generating a skeltal extension

Tags: extension, civix

I've been following the instructions to create a new extension and get the following errors when I run the civix generate:module command:

> civix generate:module org.civicrm.searchbuilderlocation

License set to AGPL-3.0 (authored by Adam Zilkie )
If this is in error, please correct info.xml and LICENSE.txt
Initalize module org.civicrm.searchbuilderlocation
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in phar:///usr/local/bin/civix/src/CRM/CivixBundle/Builder/Dirs.php on line 34

Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in phar:///usr/local/bin/civix/src/CRM/CivixBundle/Builder/Dirs.php on line 34
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in phar:///usr/local/bin/civix/src/CRM/CivixBundle/Builder/Dirs.php on line 34

Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in phar:///usr/local/bin/civix/src/CRM/CivixBundle/Builder/Dirs.php on line 34
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in phar:///usr/local/bin/civix/src/CRM/CivixBundle/Builder/Dirs.php on line 34

Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in phar:///usr/local/bin/civix/src/CRM/CivixBundle/Builder/Dirs.php on line 34
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in phar:///usr/local/bin/civix/src/CRM/CivixBundle/Builder/Dirs.php on line 34

Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in phar:///usr/local/bin/civix/src/CRM/CivixBundle/Builder/Dirs.php on line 34
Write org.civicrm.searchbuilderlocation/info.xml
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(org.civicrm.searchbuilderlocation/info.xml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in phar:///usr/local/bin/civix/src/CRM/CivixBundle/Builder/XML.php on line 71

Warning: file_put_contents(org.civicrm.searchbuilderlocation/info.xml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in phar:///usr/local/bin/civix/src/CRM/CivixBundle/Builder/XML.php on line 71
Write org.civicrm.searchbuilderlocation/searchbuilderlocation.php
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(org.civicrm.searchbuilderlocation/searchbuilderlocation.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in phar:///usr/local/bin/civix/src/CRM/CivixBundle/Builder/Template.php on line 48

Warning: file_put_contents(org.civicrm.searchbuilderlocation/searchbuilderlocation.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in phar:///usr/local/bin/civix/src/CRM/CivixBundle/Builder/Template.php on line 48
Write org.civicrm.searchbuilderlocation/searchbuilderlocation.civix.php
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(org.civicrm.searchbuilderlocation/searchbuilderlocation.civix.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in phar:///usr/local/bin/civix/src/CRM/CivixBundle/Builder/Template.php on line 48

Warning: file_put_contents(org.civicrm.searchbuilderlocation/searchbuilderlocation.civix.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in phar:///usr/local/bin/civix/src/CRM/CivixBundle/Builder/Template.php on line 48
Write org.civicrm.searchbuilderlocation/LICENSE.txt
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(org.civicrm.searchbuilderlocation/LICENSE.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in phar:///usr/local/bin/civix/src/CRM/CivixBundle/Builder/License.php on line 51

Warning: file_put_contents(org.civicrm.searchbuilderlocation/LICENSE.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in phar:///usr/local/bin/civix/src/CRM/CivixBundle/Builder/License.php on line 51

mkdir(): Permission denied in phar:///usr/local/bin/civix/src/CRM/CivixBundle/Builder/Dirs.php on line 34

It looks like it is trying to install files in /usr/local/bin/civix which is the binary location. Do I need to set a PATH variable to tell where to install files?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My read on this error doesn't suggest it's trying to write to `/usr/local/bin/civix` - just that the files that are calling `mkdir()` and `file_put_contents()` are located there.

If you call `civix` to generate a module, it will create it in the current working directory.  Check the permissions of the current directory.  If that's not conclusive, you can update the question.